# How can I listen to Apple Music from my web browser?

Tags: music, apple-music, web-browsing, websites

Is there a web player for Apple Music I can use to stream songs from my web browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple web players available:

- Apple's [official web player](https://music.apple.com) (or [the beta](https://beta.music.apple.com))
- [Musish](https://musi.sh/)
- [Zachary Seguin Music](https://music.zacharyseguin.ca/)
- [Genius](https://genius.com)

I would recommend trying one of the third party players, they have some nice features like last.fm scrobbling support and a full screen now playing view not available in the official one.

Comment: I didn't even know that there are web players besides Apple's beta player. Can you add some of the nice features the non-apple players offer?